# Should one remove highly correlated variables before doing PCA?

Tags: correlation, pca

I'm reading a paper where author discards several variables due to high correlation to other variables before doing PCA. The total number of variables is around 20.

Does this give any benefits? It looks like an overhead to me as PCA should handle this automatically.

Comment: Just a hint. Think, in what way the results of PCA will change if add more and more copies (or near copies) of one of the variables.

Comment: @type2 can you please name the paper you were reading?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

This expounds upon the insightful hint provided in a comment by @ttnphns.

**Adjoining nearly correlated variables increases the contribution of their common underlying factor to the PCA.**  We can see this geometrically.  Consider these data in the XY plane, shown as a point cloud:

[image: Scatterplot]

There is little correlation, approximately equal covariance, and the data are centered: PCA (no matter how conducted) would report two approximately equal components.

Let us now throw in a third variable $Z$ equal to $Y$ plus a tiny amount of random error.  The correlation matrix of $(X,Y,Z)$ shows this with the small off-diagonal coefficients except between the second and third rows and columns ($Y$ and $Z$):

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1. & -0.0344018 & -0.046076 \\
 -0.0344018 & 1. & 0.941829 \\
 -0.046076 & 0.941829 & 1.
\end{array}
\right)$$

Geometrically, we have displaced all the original points nearly vertically, lifting the previous picture right out of the plane of the page.  This pseudo 3D point cloud attempts to illustrate the lifting with a side perspective view (based on a different dataset, albeit generated in the same way as before):

[image: 3D plot]

The points originally lie in the blue plane and are lifted to the red dots.  The original $Y$ axis points to the right.  The resulting tilting *also stretches the points out along the YZ directions,* thereby *doubling* their contribution to the variance.  Consequently, a PCA of these new data would still identify two major principal components, but now one of them will have twice the variance of the other.

This geometric expectation is borne out with some simulations in `R`.  For this I repeated the "lifting" procedure by creating near-collinear copies of the second variable a second, third, fourth, and fifth time, naming them $X_2$ through $X_5$.  Here is a scatterplot matrix showing how those last four variables are well correlated:

[image: Scatterplot matrix]

The PCA is done using correlations (although it doesn't really matter for these data), using the first two variables, then three, ..., and finally five.  I show the results using plots of the contributions of the principal components to the total variance.

[image: PCA results]

Initially, with two almost uncorrelated variables, the contributions are almost equal (upper left corner).  After adding one variable correlated with the second--exactly as  in the geometric illustration--there are still just two major components, one now twice the size of the other.  (A third component reflects the lack of perfect correlation; it measures the "thickness" of the pancake-like cloud in the 3D scatterplot.)  After adding another correlated variable ($X_4$), the first component is now about three-fourths of the total; after a fifth is added, the first component is nearly four-fifths of the total.  In all four cases components after the second would likely be considered inconsequential by most PCA diagnostic procedures; in the last case it's possible some procedures would conclude there is only *one* principal component worth considering.

We can see now that **there may be merit in discarding variables thought to be measuring the same underlying (but "latent") aspect of a collection of variables**, because including the nearly-redundant variables can cause the PCA to overemphasize their contribution.  There is nothing *mathematically* right (or wrong) about such a procedure; it's a judgment call based on the analytical objectives and knowledge of the data.  But it should be abundantly clear that **setting aside variables known to be strongly correlated with others can have a substantial effect on the PCA results.**

---

Here is the `R` code.

```
n.cases <- 240               # Number of points.
n.vars <- 4                  # Number of mutually correlated variables.
set.seed(26)                 # Make these results reproducible.
eps <- rnorm(n.vars, 0, 1/4) # Make "1/4" smaller to *increase* the correlations.
x <- matrix(rnorm(n.cases * (n.vars+2)), nrow=n.cases)
beta <- rbind(c(1,rep(0, n.vars)), c(0,rep(1, n.vars)), cbind(rep(0,n.vars), diag(eps)))
y <- x%*%beta                # The variables.
cor(y)                       # Verify their correlations are as intended.
plot(data.frame(y))          # Show the scatterplot matrix.

# Perform PCA on the first 2, 3, 4, ..., n.vars+1 variables.
p <- lapply(2:dim(beta)[2], function(k) prcomp(y[, 1:k], scale=TRUE))

# Print summaries and display plots.
tmp <- lapply(p, summary)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
tmp <- lapply(p, plot)
```

Comment: +1, beautiful figures. What did you use for the top 2? The 1st looks like it's hand-drawn.

Comment: @gung I used a variant of the code at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11350/xkcd-style-graphs for the first figure. It has long been known that adding a little random jittering to text or an image can make it look warmer and more accessible. ($\TeX$ itself was originally built on [Metafont](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metafont), which Donald Knuth designed after a deep study of typography; he included such built-in variation.) For some graphics, like the pseudo 3D scatterplot in the second figure, the jittering technique adds little or is distracting, so I did not use it there.

Comment: That is very enlightening, whuber. I learned something new.

Comment: @whuber is like the hippest statistician -- using XKCD plots like a pro.

Comment: Re: `it's possible some procedures would conclude there is only one principal component worth considering` - this is why you should always retain components that have variances near 1 (if your interpreting the components as underlying latent traits).

Comment: +1, so in a word, it's recommended to remove highly correlated variables before PCA, right?

Comment: @logan In another word, no. Allow me to direct your attention to a sentence late in this post: "There is nothing mathematically right (or wrong) about such a procedure; it's a judgment call based on the analytical objectives and knowledge of the data."

Comment: As a follow up, linearly dependent variables, on the other hand, wouldn't affect the vectors that end up getting chosen, right? And "highly correlated" $\neq$ "linearly dependent"?

Comment: @Learning Linear dependence is the most extreme form of high correlation.  To understand the meaning you attach to "affect," one would have to know what you are comparing this situation to.

Comment: @whuber I am comparing this to exactly this situation. Linearly dependent vectors would make the matrix not full rank anymore. But if linear dependence is the most extreme case of correlation, does that mean that linearly dependent vectors also affect the eigenvalues in a way that makes us perhaps choose certain eigenvectors? Do linear dependence fall into this category of "correlated variables affecting PCA"?

Comment: @whuber And is there a theoretical analysis of how linearly dependent vectors affect the eigenvalues?

Comment: @whuber Is there any way we can avoid this without discarding variables?

Comment: You are asking and re-asking the same question, over and over, and its answer is the focus of my post here.

Comment: @whuber I thought about it, and it makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @whuber Can you please refer to some literature where this is discussed futher? I understand your point that if the same latent variable is driving two correlated variables then the impact of the latent variable is overemphasized. But I want to think through if there is ever a case where there isn't a common latent variable and perhaps it is a good idea that to include the correlated variables.

Comment: @Amatya I do not know of any literature where this issue is specifically raised and analyzed.  That likely reflects a lack of comprehensive knowledge of the literature rather than an absence of interest in the topic, though, because a great deal has been written about PCA and techniques derived from PCA.  Nevertheless, I doubt there are any general rules concerning selection of variables for PCA, because how you proceed must depend on the application as well as on the correlational structure of the data.

Comment: This is really good. If possible can you explain it in layman terms? Why does variance increase when we have correlated features/variables?

Comment: @whuber, thanks for this great answer. I am conducting EFA and have one variable with high correlations with several others. I want to remove it before doing EFA, but need to support this with reference in the paper. Any pointer?

Comment: @Rakib It might be difficult to support your decision solely through a reference to an authority, because the decision relies on the circumstances, your objectives, and your judgment more than anything else.  I hope this thread might help you make that decision and offer your own justification for it.

Comment: @whuber I am confused why " The resulting tilting also stretches the points out along the YZ directions, thereby doubling their contribution to the variance." Since $Z = Y + \epsilon$, isn't the stretching only in the +/- Z direction and not in the Y direction?

Comment: @Iamanon I invite you to ponder the 3D figure.

Comment: @whuber Yes, that's what I referred to. Just to make sure, the blue plane is the x-y plane, correct?

Comment: @Iamanon Yes, that's right. The positive x axis points out at you while the positive y axis points to the right, as is conventional.

Answer (score 52):

I will further **illustrate** the same process and idea as @whuber did, but with the loading plots, - because loadings are the essense of PCA results.

Here is three 3 analyses. In the first, we have two variables, $X_1$ and $X_2$ (in this example, they do not correlate). In the second, we added $X_3$ which is almost a copy of $X_2$ and therefore correlates with it strongly. In the third, we still similarly added 2 more "copies" of it: $X_4$ and $X_5$.

The plots of loadings of the first 2 principal components then go. Red spikes on the plots tell of correlations between the variables, so that the bunch of several spikes is where a cluster of tightly correlated variables is found. The components are the grey lines; the relative "strength" of a component (its relative eigenvalue magnitude) is given by weight of the line.

[image]

Two effects of adding the "copies" can be observed:

1. Component 1 becomes stronger and stronger, and Component 2 weaker
   and weaker.
2. Orientation of the components change: at first,
   Component 1 went in the middle between $X_1$ and $X_2$; as we added
   $X_3$ to $X_2$ Component 1 immediately re-oriented itself to follow
   the emergent bunch of variables; and you may be sure that after we
   further added two more variables to the bunch the attachment of
   Component 1 to that bunch of closely correlated variables became
   more undisputable.

I will not resume the moral because @whuber already did it.

---

**Addition**. Below are some pictures in response to @whuber's comments. It is about a distinction between "variable space" and "subject space" and how components orient themselves here and there. Three bivariate PCAs are presented: first row analyzes $r=0$, second row analyzes $r=0.62$, and third row $r=0.77$. The left column is scatterplots (of standardized data) and the right column is loading plots.

On a scatterplot, the correlation between $X_1$ and $X_2$ is rendered as oblongness of the cloud. The angle (its cosine) between a component line and a variable line is the corresponding *eigenvector* element. Eigenvectors are identical in all three analyses (so the angles on all 3 graphs are the same). [But, it is true, that with $r=0$ *exactly*, eigenvectors (and hence the angles) are theoretically arbitrary; because the cloud is perfectly "round" any pair of orthogonal lines coming through the origin could serve as the two components, - even $X_1$ and $X_2$ lines themselves could be chosen as the components.] The coordinates of data points (200 subjects) onto a component are component scores, and their sum of squares devided by 200-1 is the component's *eigenvalue*.

On a loading plot, the points (vectors) are variables; they spread the space which is 2-dimensional (because we have 2 points + origin) but is actually a reduced 200-dimensional (number of subjects) "subject space". Here the angle (cosine) between the red vectors is $r$. The vectors are of equal, unit length, because the data had been standardized. The first component is such a dimension axis in this space which rushes towards the overal accumulation of the points; in case of just 2 variables it is always the bisector between $X_1$ and $X_2$ (but adding a 3rd variable can deflect it anyhow). The angle (cosine) between a variable vector and a component line is the correlation between them, and because the vectors are unit lenght and the components are orthogonal, this is nothing else than the coordinates, the *loading*. Sum of squared loadings onto the component is its *eigenvalue* (the component just orients itself in this subject space so as to maximize it)

[image]

---

**Addition2.** In **Addition** above I was speaking about "variable space" and "subject space" as if they are incompatible together like water and oil. I had to reconsider it and may say that - at *least when we speak about PCA* - both spaces are isomorphic in the end, and by that virtue we can correctly display all the PCA details - data points, variable axes, component axes, variables as points, - on a single undistorted biplot.

Below are the scatterplot (variable space) and the loading plot (component space, which is subject space by its genetic origin). Everything that could be shown on the one, could also be shown on the other. The pictures *are identical*, only rotated by 45 degrees (and reflected, in this particular case) relative each other. That was a PCA of variables v1 and v2 (standardized, thus it was *r* that was analyzed). Black lines on the pictures are the variables as axes; green/yellow lines are the components as axes; blue points are the data cloud (subjects); red points are the variables displayed as points (vectors).

[image]

Comment: +1 interesting illustration.  BTW, your second observation is an artifact of the data: the orientation changed because in the first case the correlation was *perfect,* giving a two-dimensional eigenspace. (This is extremely rare in real data; it usually means a database mistake was made and one variable is a linear re-expression of another.) The software was free to choose *any* orthogonal basis for that space, arbitrarily. Just the tiniest amount of correlation would have removed this degeneracy. I think, therefore, that you over-interpret this reorientation phenomenon.

Comment: @whuber, Maybe I don't understand you. What "perfect" correlation? _r_ bw X1 and X2 was .003; and it could'd been any, for example .503. That would be the _cos_ of the angle bw the two red vectors on the plot. Whatever the _r_, the 1st PC is always the bisector while only 2 variables are in analysis. I guess that your note `The software was free to choose any orthogonal basis for that space, arbitrarily` applies to round cloud in _variable space_ (i.e. data scatterplot, like the 1st picture in your answer), but loading plot is _subject space_ where variables, not cases, are points (vectors).

Comment: Sorry; I meant perfect *lack* of correlation. In your analyses, did you use covariance or correlation or otherwise standardize the data rows or columns?  (Perhaps I misunderstand, but I do not find your distinction between "subject" and "variable" spaces meaningful in this context: both the original basis vectors and the data are elements of, say, $\mathbb{R}^5$; the "loading plot" is a projection onto the subspace generated by the first two PCs. I believe most people would take the "subject" space to have 240 dimensions in my simulation: I didn't illustrate that with a scatterplot!)

Comment: I used correlations (notice the matrix and the fact that the red vectors are essentially the same length). Yes, subject space _is_ a tupsy-torvey scatterplot with _n_ axes (subjects) and _p_ points (variables). Of course, all n-p dimensions are redundant and any set of p variables can be plotted in p-dimensional subject space, but this doesn't turn it into a variable space! I'll just add a picture to my answer.

Comment: +1, thanks for the additional contribution, @ttnphns. This is turning from what I originally thought was a fairly simple question into a fabulously informative thread.

Comment: @whuber, I think I begin to understand what you meant. I've added a picture which shows that "variable space" and "subject space" eventually converged into one.

Comment: Is there a mathematical interpretation? I mean if some variables are highly correlated, then the covariance matrix $C$ should have some large items at those variables, and then by PCA, the PC's found by eigen-decomposition of $C$ should be affected somehow.

Comment: @logan You can't say anything simple about the relative sizes of components of the covariance matrix. Concerning the *correlation matrix*, it is possible to have *perfect correlation* among $m$ variables (that is, at least one linear dependence among them) without any of the off-diagonal elements exceeding $1/(m-1)$ in size (which gets pretty small for large $m$). PCA and eigenanalysis in general yield subtler information than a look at the sizes of the matrix entries can achieve.

Answer (score 4):

Without details from your paper, I would conjecture that this discarding of highly-correlated variables was done merely to save off on computational power or workload. I cannot see a reason for why PCA would 'break' for highly correlated variables. Projecting data back onto the bases found by PCA has the effect of whitening the data, (or de-correlating them). That is the whole point behind PCA.

Comment: Did you read the hint by @ttnphns?  PCA pays attention not just to the eigenvectors (which you discuss) but also to the eigenvalues (which you ignore).  This is critical, because the eigenvalues are used to determine which components to retain and which ones to drop.

Comment: @whuber Yes...yes I think I get it now. So essentially, more correlated variables will over-emphasize particular eigenvectors, (directions), and if there are many correlated variables, then there would be so many more overemphasized 'fake' directions, that drown out an 'original' eigenvector/direction that would have otherwise been easily seen. Am I understanding you right?

Comment: That's pretty close, Mohammad. The reality is that a set of correlated variables might "load" onto several principal components (eigenvectors), so including many variables from such a set will differentially weight *several* eigenvectors--and thereby change the directions of all eigenvectors, too.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding correlated variables are ok, because PCA outputs vectors that are orthogonal.

Comment: You're right, but would you mind explaining why orthogonality has any bearing on whether or not to discard variables in advance?

Answer (score -2):

Well, it depends on your algorithm. Highly correlated variables may mean an ill-conditioned matrix. If you use an algorithm that's sensitive to that it might make sense. But I dare saying that most of the modern algorithms used for cranking out eigenvalues and eigenvectors are robust to this. Try removing the highly correlated variables. Do the eigenvalues and eigenvector change by much? If they do, then ill-conditioning might be the answer. Because highly correlated variables don't add information, the PCA decomposition shouldn't change

Comment: Unfortunately, the PCA *does* change: it's almost guaranteed.

Comment: @whuber Wow, huge amount of responses, and very informative. Sorry for my comment, it was totally wrong. My bad. Very informative answer BTW

Comment: I learn the most from totally wrong answers, Juancentro--especially my own, which fortunately rarely get out in public :-). I had thoughts similar to yours until @ttnphns left a comment.

Answer (score -2):

Depends on what principle component selection method you use doesn't it?

I tend to use any principle component with an eigenvalue > 1. So it wouldn't effect me.

And from the examples above even the scree plot method would usually pick the right one. IF YOU KEEP ALL BEFORE THE ELBOW. However if you simply picked the principle component with the 'dominant' eigenvalue you would be lead astray. But that is not the right way to use a scree plot!

Comment: Welcome to the site, Chris. Unfortunately, neither of these ad-hoc procedures are particularly defensible. Notice that in the first case you could not change the shape of your data at all and go from selecting *all* of them to selecting *none* of them (just by multiplying everything by a constant).