# Are overestimated correlations detrimental for component scores of PCA?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, correlation, pca, multivariate-analysis

In some cases, we may want to use principal component analysis on several time-series variables, or some regionalized random variables (i.e., spatial varying variables). The variability of these variables usually contain large-scale trend, which might result in the variables being correlated. Therefore, the correlation obtained from conventional multivariate statistics might be overestimated. I want to know what is the effect of the overestimated correlation for PCA scores? Whether should I detrend the variables before performing PCA?

Comment: Overestimated relative what? PCA itself is indifferent whether correlations in the input variables are "true" or "twisted". Sure, the magnitude of correlations [affect PCA results](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/50537/3277). One should consider carefully potentially useful transformations before PCA.

Comment: @ttnphns Thank you for your answer. "Overestimated" here I mean the absolute correlation coefficient is larger than that for the reference variables (without simulated trend term added). I understand you agree with that I should detrend variables before calculating their correlation coeffcient.