# PCA - Feature Scaling

Tags: machine-learning, pca, dimensionality-reduction, standardization, feature-scaling

I have been reading that the features should be standardized before performing PCA but I couldn't relate to my understanding of the same.

PCA try to project the dataset in the direction of maximum variance and the whole idea of PCA is the dimensionality reduction. So, If I achieve the maximum variance in less components, then that is preferred over achieving in more components, right?

In other words, I am getting the cumulative explained variance ratio of ~99% in 2 components when using non standardized data whereas the standardized data takes ~10 components to achieve the same variance. So, why standardizing is preferred prior to performing PCA?

Other that dimensionality reduction, if the intention is to prepare the dataset for an input for a regression model, it it better to have more features explaining the variance?

**PCA - Non Standardized data(2 components)**
[image: PCA - 2 components - non standardized]

**PCA - Standardized data(10 components)**
[image: PCA - 10 components - Standardized]

I would appreciate it if you could correct my understanding.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: This question seems to start half-way through an attempt to solve some (unspecified) problem. What problem are you trying to solve, and how do PCA and standardization fit in with helping you solve it? Also, we have a great many questions about [tag:pca], standardization and both topics together; they can be found using the Search feature.

Comment: Why stop here? We can actually do much better: just multiply the first column of your dataset by 10^15, and you'll find variance explained by the first component of >99.9 percent ;)

Comment: Re "[is] it better to have more features explaining the variance," this is answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50537/.  Re "should be standardized:" this is, at best, generic advice.  It cannot be taken literally as what one always should do.  Whether it's any good depends on the nature of the data and what kinds of relationships you are exploring.  "Prepare ... for an input to a regression model" is vague because it doesn't explain what role the PCs are intended to play in that model or even indicate why a preliminary PCA might be helpful.

Comment: @Sycorax, the original problem is to classify the breast cancer dataset using KNN model and in the solution the author used PCA without standardization  to reduce the dataset from 30 features to 2 and then performed KNN, so my question is why the PCA without standardization is done over with standardization?

Comment: See: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53/pca-on-correlation-or-covariance and the links therein

Comment: @Sycorax: Thank you