# Methods to quantify if the sum of two variables is close to a constant

Tags: methodology

In my data set, each individual has two properties, a and b. It seems that `a + b` is close to 10. Which statistic method could I use to test if this is true?

I really appreciate your help!

```
 Person a   b
    1   2   8
    2   2   9
    3   3   7
    4   2   8
    5   4   6
    6   2   8
    7   4   6
    8   2   9
    9   2   8
    10  5   5
```

Comment: "a+b close to some constant" is equivalent to testing whether $a$, $b$, and a constant (nonzero) vector are linearly dependent.  Thus, your question is a special case of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16327/testing-for-linear-dependence-among-the-columns-of-a-matrix.  However, it is such a straightforward problem that it admits other solutions not applicable in that thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a third column a+b:

```
10
11
10
10
10
10
10
11
10
10
```

Get the mean and standard deviation: $\mu=10.2$ and $\sigma=0.42$

Test whether the mean is far from 10: t-stat$: \frac{10.2-10}{0.42/\sqrt{10}}=1.5$

Since t-statistic is lower than the critical value at 95%, then we conclude that it may indeed be 10, the sum of two columns.

Comment: Thank you! Just figured out that this question is a simple One Sample T Test. Here is the [link](http://www.statisticshowto.com/one-sample-t-test/) for more details in case other people would be interested in.

Comment: yes, I forgot to divide by $\sqrt n$, corrected